# Cannot Interact with Command Prompt In Angular

Tags: angular

I'm very new to `Angular`, and went to the [documentation - hero](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt1) and tried it. And I need to generate new component by using the cmd `ng generate component heroes` .

But I can't interact with the cmd, or let me type for the next line. Is there any other way to proceed?

[image: cmd]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open a new `cmd` prompt and go to the project location and type `ng g c heroes`.

in your screenshot, you have started the server and so you cant do anything here. Open a new terminal and try the command.

Comment: Can I do this manually? Like create a `component` under app, and manually created the 3 files - heroes.component.html (.css & .ts) ?

Comment: Yes, u can create a component manually as well. For that, make sure you are adding it in `app.module.ts` under `@NgModule`'s `declaration` section. For services, you'll have to add under `provider` of `@NgModule`. The DI(Dependency injection) part is handled by angular-cli while creating a component/provider etc

Comment: Many thanks, I just run multiple terminal in Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Great! same as opening new terminal ;)